# What is the usage of the "word" after the CONSTRAINT keyword?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, constraints, create-table

What is the usage of the **"word" after the CONSTRAINT** keyword? Can I write any name for it?

I have never used that "word" which we write after the CONSTRAINT keyword.

For example, **FK_PersonOrder** is the word for the following example.

```
CREATE TABLE Orders (
    OrderID int NOT NULL,
    OrderNumber int NOT NULL,
    PersonID int,
    PRIMARY KEY (OrderID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_PersonOrder FOREIGN KEY (PersonID)
    REFERENCES Persons(PersonID)
);
```

Comment: It's the name of the of the constraint. You don't strictly need it, as MySQL will give it one if you don't - but you have more control over it and can give a way better description if you do. The name `FK_PersonOrder` would mean you have a reference between the Persons and Orders tables, so its a good and descriptive name.

Comment: @Qirel Thanks. If we never used that word after creating the table, does it matter having a descriptive name?

Comment: You can use the name to manipulate the constraint. For instance in `ALTER TABLE Orders DROP CONSTRAINT FK_PersonOrder`.

Comment: It will not impact anything unless you at some point need to alter it or drop it. Its still possible either way - as I said, MySQL will give it a name if you don't. But the name won't be descriptive, so you might be a bit confused for a bit trying to work out what it is. But it'll work just the same.

Answer (score 1):

This refers to the name of the `CONSTRAINT` that will be created in the database.

You can use pretty much any name you want (You can even use the column name if you so choose!), what's more important for readability and maintainability's sake is that you use a consistent naming convention for your constraints. An example of this would be `PK_[column name]` for primary keys, `FK_[column name]_[referenced table name]` for foreign keys, and `IDX_[column name(s)]` for indexes.